# I am trying to get my PHP and form working correctly

Tags: php, html, forms

Hey I have a simple coding issue and I am hoping someone can spot the error of my ways.

I have a contact page http://mattmcdougall.ca/contact
this page has a form that is connected to a form PHP.

it is half working, I receive the email with ONLY the name subject and recipient (me). I do not get the other information in the form. (phone number and content do not get placed in the email) ALSO, I want the website to bring the person filling out the form to http://mattmcdougall.ca/contactdone currently it goes to a blank form.php page

here is the form code and PHP code, please feel free to clean up PHP as I used a template I found online.

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" class="formtext">
<input name="Name" type="text" value="enter name" maxlength="60"><br>
<input name="Email" value="enter email" type="text"><br>
<input name="Phone Number" value="enter phone#"type="text"><br><br>
<textarea name="Interest" cols="60" rows="10">Interest?</textarea><br><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit"><form
```

and the PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Matt McDougall Photography</TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
$name = $_POST['name']; //senders name
$email = $_POST['email']; //senders e-mail adress
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$recipient = "matt@mattmcdougall.ca"; //recipient
$mail_body = $_POST['interest']; //mail body
$subject = "interested client"; //subject
$header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; 
mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $phone, $header); //mail command :)
if(mail)
'http://mattmcdougall.ca/contactdone.html';
else
echo "Sorry Something Went Wonky, Please Try Again!";
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Please describe your actual problem. You've listed a few vague feature requests for us to write for you, but haven't really asked a question.

Comment: Meagar, I am sorry allow me to rephrase the above comment. How do I get the Mail boolean to send all the information? how do I get the submit button to take a client to the contactdone.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to change the name of your form elements to match the params that you're expecting to receive via $_POST.

Right now you have (for example):

```
<input name="Phone Number" value="enter phone#"type="text"><br><br>
```

But you're going to need to name it:

```
<input name="phone" value="enter phone#"type="text"><br><br>
```

The name attribute is what is going to be submitted via the form to your PHP script.  You need to use the same name on both sides.

Also what is the $phone variable in your mail function call? Those areas are reserved for additional headers and not just $phone.  You'll need to concatenate the phone number into the $mail_body like so (with additional formatting of course):

```
$mail_body = $mail_body . " " . $phone;
```

This is the correct signature:

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

Edit: In addition to all of this, your $header is also wrong as it's trying to use the $Name variable which does not exist.  The $name variable does exist.

---

I think this below should solve your problems.

**Form:**

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" class="formtext">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" maxlength="60"><br>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email"><br>
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone #"><br><br>

  <textarea name="interest" cols="60" rows="10" placeholder="Interest?"></textarea><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**form.php**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$interest = $_POST["interest"];

$to = "matt@mattmcdougall.ca";
$subject = "Interested Client";
$headers = "From: {$name} <{$email}>\r\n";

$mail_body = <<<EMAIL
Name: {$name}
Phone: {$phone}
Message:
{$interest}
EMAIL;

$mail_success = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);

if($mail_success) {
  echo "http://mattmcdougall.ca/contactdone.html"; // are you trying to redirect to here?
} else {
  echo "Sorry, something went wonky! Please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: I would also add to the above answer and use placeholder="enter phone#" instead of value.

Comment: So now I am overly confused by this. my confusion comes in because I do not have $to or $message. On top of the confusion there, I am getting syntax error based on that code (yes I adjusted the [,[,]] how I thought it should have been). As for the wrong value names, I swore I fixed that. Must have been a bad save. Either way thanks everyone who has replied

Comment: Matti2ed please check my edit above to see sample code to fix it.  Please note that I'm saving off the $mail_success (which mail returns a boolean) to check in the if.  I am also using a heredoc style message body which I believe will preserve line breaks in the message.  If it doesn't just do concatenation with CRLFs.

Comment: Caleb,Thank you!That helped a ton breaking it down like that. Even at that it makes it easy for me to understand later on. It is emailing me now. the last part of this, the redirect, as I expected it directs to a page saying in the upper left corner "http://mattmcdougall.ca/contactdone" because of the echo command. I just need an IF command that will pop up "contactdone"

Comment: Hey Caleb, I figured it out. I removed the top header portion and it fixed the issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP POST variables are case sensitive**, and the names of the input fields do not match that of those in PHP. `<input type="text" name="datanamehere" />` with `$_POST["datanamehere"]`. Like what other answers said:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" class="formtext">
<input name="name" placeholder="Full name" type="text" maxlength="60"><br>
<input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email"><br>
<input name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" type="tel"><br><br>
<textarea name="interest" placeholder="Interested in?" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Notice I changed the `value` to `placeholder`, and used `type="email"` and `type="tel"`.

**form.php**

```
$name = $_POST['name']; //senders name
$email = $_POST['email']; //senders e-mail adress
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$recipient = "matt@mattmcdougall.ca"; //recipient
$mail_body = $_POST['interest']; //mail body
$subject = "interested client"; //subject
$header = "From: ". $name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; 
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header))  //mail command :)
    'http://mattmcdougall.ca/contactdone.html';
else
    echo "Sorry Something Went Wonky, Please Try Again!";
```

As they said, `mail()` is a function returning a boolean. Wrap it around `if` to check for success.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to have worked. I feel like I am missing something. Thanks for the place holder tip I changed it everywhere.

Comment: $header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";  <-- change the uppercase N to lower case.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned... I already did that, same results

Comment: Remove $phone from mail function

Answer (score 0):

Your element names do not match the ones in the PHP code and your form is not properly closed using .

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" class="formtext">
<input name="name" type="text" value="enter name" maxlength="60"><br>
<input name="email" type="text" value="enter email"><br>
<input name="phone" type="text" value="enter phone#"><br><br>
<textarea name="Interest" cols="60" rows="10">Interest?</textarea><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

mail is a function, so checking it in the 'if' by just writing mail isn't going to work.

try this instead

```
if(mail()): 
// go to contactdone.html
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
exit();
else:
echo "Sorry Something Went Wonky, Please Try Again!";
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try,

- if(mail)'http://mattmcdougall.ca/contactdone.html' is not going to do
  anything, try using Header('Location
  http://mattmcdougall.ca/contactdone.html')
- Whenever you use $_POST the parameter name inside the [''] need to
  match your input names (Example: `<input name="interest" type="text">`
  would be `$_POST['interest']`)
- If you want to show text inside an input use placeholder="enter
  phone#" instead of value.